# Rails 4: javascript_include_tag generates wrong MIME type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, content-type

I added into my application.html.erb the following code:

*<%= javascript_include_tag "/js/bootstrap.min.js",  :type => "text/javascript" %>*

However, the javascript is not working in the browser, *"because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled"*

I checked by Fiddler and YES - for this file **Content-Type is text/html**

WHY is that? I consider it to be a very annoying (actually, thie is a show-stopper for me) defect, because I explicitly require the Content-Type to be "text/javascript" (or "application/javascript")

My configuration:
Rails 4.0
Ruby 2.2
config.assets.enabled or disabled - tried both...

Comment: what is the folder heirarchy where the bootstrap.min.js file is?